# Xcode Can't remove UIBarbuttonItem without getting error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So i started with my app with 2 buttons in my calenderview : a day and a week button.
Now i want to just use 1 button and dynamically change the name of it (that part works)
I am using the weekbutton for that. But now I want to remove the day button.
But i cant get it out of my program.

I tried first deleting the link in .xib
Then i delete the button.
Then i remove it from the .h file, and then from .m 
It always results in the same error :

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key dayButton.'

Cant see why i just cant remove the button...

Comment: Did you remove the day button from the xib?. This error is commonly occurs when the outlet of the button is not properly connected

Comment: i did first remove reference outlets, then the send actions, then the buttons...

Comment: clean & build your code

Comment: already did, still same error

Comment: Can you share your project if it is sample project?

Comment: it's no sample project i am afraid

Answer (score 1):

You`ve deleted outlet from code .h/.m file, but somewhere in .xib something is still connected to deleted outlet. Recheck all connections in .xib file to be sure that they have appropriate declaration in .h file.

Comment: there is no connection, i checked. I dont see it in fileowner or in first responder to..

Comment: You might have outlets at any added object, not only at the file owner. Please confirm you've checked everything.

Comment: ive checked every object that is in the xib. I even used the older files which hand't had the button still the same error